# Save a byte from int with bit mask and pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, bit-manipulation

How can I save the second byte from an int value? Say, we have `int a` and `char c`.

1. With pointers we get the address of the variable `a` like so `char* pC = (char*)&a;` What is next to do to get the second byte from int to save to char?
2. With masks it should be like so `((a << 8) >> 24)` . But why is it so and what to do next to save the 2nd byte?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Can you please share the complete code? I think I am getting your "problem" but I am not totally sure why you are asking

Comment: The second bit will have the value `2`. So mask with `2` to see if the second bit is set. If you want to use it in a condition, remember that everything non-zero is "true".

Comment: Also remember about [*endianness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). If you have a pointer to a series of bytes, the "second bit" could be at different positions.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX basically this is a complete task. And I shared code that i am thinking of.

Comment: The task is complete of course. But you provided only two statements saying something is a mask and then asking why? I can give you a code which does what you want. But I think this will not help you understanding what happens "under the hood". So we want to help you step through step to get a better grasp in what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

You can do basic bit masking. Say, `a = 0x12 34 56 78`. If you will `AND` `a` with `0x00 00 FF 00`, you will have `0x00 00 56 00` remaining. Then you can shift your bits 8 times in order to obtain `0x00 00 00 56`. You also don't even need pointers for that.

Let's show it in binary for better illustration:

```
00010010 00110100 01010110 01111000 (a in binary)
00000000 00000000 11111111 00000000 (bitmask)
00000000 00000000 01010110 00000000 (AND result)
00000000 00000000 00000000 01010110 (>> 8 result)
```

Code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 0x12345678;
    int result = (a & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;

    printf("a : 0x%x , result : 0x%x\n", a, result);

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs `a : 0x12345678 , result : 0x56` which is the second byte from your original integer. Similarly, you can obtain any part of the integer using basic bitwise operations.

Comment: many thanks to you. But if back to the initial question, how to do that with pointers? And if I make like so ((a << 8) >> 24) what is the logic behind that? We move 8 bits lo the left to getthe first cell of the memory block and then we need to fullfil the other cells with zeros with >> 24. Why 24?

Comment: Let `int a = 0x12345678;`, `char *pc = ((char *) &a) + 1;` would point to the 2nd last byte. And about that trick, 8 bits are 1 byte and 24 bits are 3 bytes. If we do `int b = a << 8;` b becomes `0x34 56 78 00` we just reset the byte before the second byte. Then we do `int b = (a<<8)>>24;` and b becomes `0x00 00 00 34` which only contains the second byte. First operation helped us to get rid of the byte before `34` and `>>24` got rid of the bytes after `34` as well as leaning our desired byte to the right of the number.

Comment: No problem, mind picking this answer as the solution and upvote?